# ModSecurity: How to increase SecRequestBodyLimit for specific website REQUEST_URI?

Tags: mod-security

I received this error in my ModSecurity logs:

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Eq' with parameter `0' against variable `REQBODY_ERROR' (Value: `1' ) [file "/etc/nginx/modsec/modsecurity.conf"] [line "75"] [id "200002"] [rev ""] [msg "Failed to parse request body."] [data "Request body excluding files is bigger than the maximum expected."] [severity "2"] [ver ""] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [hostname "***.***.***.***"] [uri "/add/submit.php"] [unique_id "167296149027.413348"] [ref "v0,1"]
```

From what I understand, the request body exceeds the default `SecRequestBodyLimit` parameter that is set in the main ModSecurity config. It is not unusual for some users to submit highly formatted listings on this specific page that are larger than the default 131kb request body limit

How do I write a custom exclusion rule to increase `SecRequestBodyLimit` only for my "/add/submit.php" page on a specific domain? I'm looking for the proper writing of a rule similar to this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@pm example.com www.example.com" \
    "id:100001,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_URI "@pm /add/submit.php" \
    "ctl:requestBodyLimit=1048576"
```

The rule above doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "modsecurity_rules_file" directive Rules error. File: /etc/nginx/modsec/coreruleset-4.0.0-rc1/rules/REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf. Line: 410. Column: 30. Expecting an action, got:  ctl:requestBodyLimit=1048576" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:32
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ModSecurity Core Rule Set *Developer on Duty* here. It's important to note that there are several different request body limits in ModSecurity. They handle different situations and prevent different kinds of attacks.

Looking at this part of your log line:

> [data "**Request body excluding files** is bigger than the maximum expected."]

we can tell that the [`SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit`](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#secrequestbodynofileslimit) limit has been exceeded. This deals with non-file related request body data. You want to keep this limit as low as possible to reduce the chances of certain types of attacks taking place against your WAF.

I wrote a [detailed blog post about this exact topic](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/handling-large-requests-with-a-waf-while-avoiding-dos-attacks/) a few months ago, with diagrams and examples. It's worth a read to better understand the different request body limits, what they do, and why they exist.

In Apache, you could increase the `SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit` only for the specific location where it's needed, like so:

```
<Location "/user/profile/avatar-upload.php">
    SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 200000
</Location>
```

I'm sure you could do something similar/identical in nginx; I don't personally use nginx so I can't give you the specifics.

Comment: This worked, I combined your solution of using `SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit` with Esa's nginx block format and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple override for a location, add to your Nginx configuration (`server{}` block):

```
location /add/submit.php {
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRequestBodyLimit 1048576';
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 1048576';
}
```

Comment: I had also added `SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit` do this block and then it seemed to work.